# Using jQuery change event to filter a table but is working on every table on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, onchange

I am using the change event to filter a table on a page, but for some reason it is acting on every table on the page.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$('#inputFilter').change(function() {
        var that = this;
        $.each($('tr'),
        function(i, val) {
            if ($(val).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                    $('tr').eq(i).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                    $('tr').eq(i).show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Where `inputFilter` is the id of the input of the filter and `data_fm_op` is the id of the table.

Why is it affecting all tables?

Comment: May you try to replace $.each by $(this).each ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP doesn't want it to effect each table, just the one they find. So you would need to take out the .each all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each($('tr'),
```

iterates over each `<tr />` on the page. Change it to

```
$.each($('#data_fm_op').find('tr'),
```

to get only the rows of `#data_fm_op`

Answer (score 0):

because you use $.each("tr"), you have the put the id of tabletry this:

```
<script>
$('#inputFilter').change(function() {
        var that = this;
        $('#data_fm_op').find('tr').each(function(i, val) {
            if ($(val).text().indexOf($(that).val()) == -1) {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                    $('tr').eq(i).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $('#data_fm_op').animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                },
                50,
                function() {
                    $('tr').eq(i).show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```